# Display a list in Grid view for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How Can I display a list in two columns for an application in windows phone 8?

items.xaml.cs:

```
public async void Initi()
{
     var itemsManagement = new ItemsManagement();
     var itemList = await itemsManagement.GetAllItems();
     var templist = from c in itemList.Data orderby c.Name, c.Id ascending select c;
     NameList.ItemsSource = templist;
}
```

items.xaml :

```
<ListBox x:Name="NameList">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
                  </TextBlock>
             </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

This solution displays my list in one column, I would like a display in two columns

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [this](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Create a grid inside your DataTemplate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: How to do to haven't duplicate datas?

Answer (score 1):

Use a LongListSelector, and set [LayoutMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.layoutmode(v=vs.105).aspx) to Grid and [GridCellSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.gridcellsize(v=vs.105).aspx) to half the page width.

```
<phone:LongListSelector
    LayoutMode="Grid"
    GridCellSize="200,20"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to do in this way:

```
<ListBox x:Name="NameList">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="200"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
           </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```