# How to make a grid in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm new in Windows Phone 8 development, so I need a help, because I want to create a page which has a grid/table, like we have the ASP.NET grid, is it possible?

I want to create an app with championship classification, so I need a table to show the teams classifications, points and etc. I have already saw apps in store with this grid like I want to reproduce, inclusive the bing Sports app has one.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Your question is very broad, and doesn't show any evidence of research on your part. You're stating requirements here, not a problem. You need to research Windows Phone 8 app development and make an attempt to write some code. If you encounter problems writing the code, post more questions.

Comment: @ChrisMantle I have already developed simple apps to Windows Phone 8. In my research I don't find if is possible to create a Grid like ASP.NET. My questions is if is possible to create a grid like ASP.NET and if exists a control to do it.

Comment: @PedroGalinatti OK. Seems like JPack has provided some useful links, hope they're helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible I suggest googling the questions you have before you post ^_^ Posts in Stack Overflow are for questions that arent readily available. 
Here is a similar stackoverflow question: 
[Display a list in Grid view for windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479826/display-a-list-in-grid-view-for-windows-phone-8)

If your very new to programming maybe try searching how to make .net pages and possibly codeacademy. It could also be good to view the Microsoft Website with the API's if you can understand how to use new coding tools from their instructions. I know I cant sometimes -_-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn338450#fbid=4rwU7JSFWKG
http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/making-websites-with-aspnet/making-websites-with-aspnet

I have been using the website for a long time and am only now starting to post, but be sure to do your homework first.